# When can mapply's MoreArgs argument not be replaced by R's vector recycling rules?

Tags: r, apply, mapply, optional-arguments

I'm trying to come up with an example of when `mapply`'s `MoreArgs` argument is useful. I have been utterly defeated. Outrageously, even the example given in `mapply`'s documentation is inadequate. The docs give `mapply(rep, times = 1:4, MoreArgs = list(x = 42))` as their only example of the use of `MoreArgs`, but I have found that R's vector recycling rules mean that `mapply(rep, times = 1:4, 42)` gives exactly the same output.

So when can `MoreArgs` not be replaced by just deleting the corresponding `MoreArgs = list(...)` wrapper? I tried to come up with some examples myself, but I failed every time. For example, `mapply(rnorm,1:10,11:20,MoreArgs = list(5),SIMPLIFY = FALSE)` is identical to `mapply(rnorm,1:10,11:20,5,SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`.

Following the lead of the comments, [I've also tried](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66217114/10319707) examples where we need to recycle a vector for each call to the function that `mapply` is being called on. However, it seems that `mapply` has no difference in functionality between using a list containing said vector - e.g. `list(c(0.6,0.3,0.1))` - as a `...` argument or as a `MoreArgs` argument. In the `MoreArgs` case, the content of the list is recycled as expected and in the `...` case, the vector recycling rules mean that the content of the list will be recycled in each case, giving identical functionality to `MoreArgs`. This brings me back to the original question: When can the `MoreArgs` argument of `mapply` be used to give functionality that cannot be gotten from the `...` argument and the vector recycling rules? I've yet to see a case where identical functionality cannot be gained by simply deleting the `MoreArgs=` argument and letting the relevant parts pass to `...`.

Comment: In `...` you put vectors you want to vectorize/loop/iterate over. In `MoreArgs` you put things you _don't_ want to loop over. A very simple example (similar to the one I deleted): we want to subset a data frame with indices kept in two vectors. We want to loop over the two vectors. Thus, put them in `...`. However, we _don't_ want to loop over the data frame - each set of indices obtained when 'sliding' along the vectors in `...` should be applied to the _entire_, original data frame, i.e. put the data in `MoreArgs`.

Comment: `d = data.frame(x = 1:2, y = 3:4)`; `rowix = 1:2`; `colix = 1:2`; `mapply(FUN = function(i, j, dat) dat[i, j], rowix, colix, MoreArgs = list(d))`. So stuff that you _don't want_ to iterate over should be put in `MoreArgs`, be it a data frame like here, "constant" function arguments like `na.rm = TRUE`, function parameters, other functions called by the function in `FUN`...

Comment: @Henrik I repeat my recommendation for writing that up as an answer.

Comment: Appreciated, but I assume there are already nice posts out there. [...some scrolling later...] I think e.g. this post captures the essence of what I tried to describe in my stupid toy example: ["If you don't want to iterate over parameters, stick them in the `MoreArgs= parameter`"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43789942/1851712). Just check some of the [`MoreArgs posts`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+MoreArgs) for additional, possibly more relevant posts.

Comment: @Henrik If I understand you correctly, you've got a simple and solid answer: "`mapply`'s `MoreArgs` argument can't be replaced by R's vector recycling rules because some of R's data objects cannot be recycled, e.g. data frames".

Comment: Well, I think the main question is if you _want_ the objects to be recycled. If not, put them in `MoreArgs`. My toy example happened to error if I put the data frame in `...`, but there may well be examples where the code "works" with recycling, but you simply _don't want_ recycling. Again, please refer to the post I linked to where OP describe their issue with recycling ("if I try the following: `mapply(assignCentre, xcoords, ycoords, xcentres, ycentres)` it fails" [shows an example of _undesired recycling_].

Comment: The solution was to move relevant vectors from `...` to `MoreArgs`, to _avoid_ recycling. Again, I think the distinction is more if you want to loop over the arguments or not, rather than 'can the argument be recycled'.

Comment: @Henrik I tried to follow your example in my answer. Was I faithful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've yet to see a case where identical functionality cannot be gained by simply deleting the `MoreArgs=` argument and letting the relevant parts pass to `...`.

This is wrong, but only slightly. Compare:

```
options(max.print = 50)#Before running this, make sure that you know how to undo it.

> mapply(sum,1:5,MoreArgs=list(runif(10),runif(10000)))
[1] 5019.831 5020.831 5021.831 5022.831 5023.831

> mapply(sum,1:5,list(runif(10)),list(runif(10000)))
[1] 5069.321 5070.321 5071.321 5072.321 5073.321

> mapply(sum,1:5,list(runif(10),runif(10000)))
[1]    6.658275 4984.177882    8.658275 4986.177882   10.658275

> mapply(sum,1:5,runif(10),runif(10000))
 [1] 1.750417 3.286090 3.186474 5.310268 5.962829 1.343564 2.325567 3.928796 4.955376
[10] 5.507385 1.992290 3.454536 3.399763 5.242883 5.589296 1.637056 2.964259 3.839006
[19] 5.647123 5.883139 1.863512 2.827110 3.633137 5.174900 5.365155 2.022725 3.139846
[28] 3.830624 5.064546 5.697612 1.242803 3.456888 3.726114 5.271773 5.881724 1.533730
[37] 2.489976 3.509690 5.657166 5.400823 1.972689 2.858276 3.571505 5.582752 5.482381
[46] 1.956237 2.497409 3.864434 5.389969 5.965341
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 9950 entries ]
Warning message:
In mapply(sum, 1:5, list(runif(10), runif(10000))) :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter
```

In the first case, every element of the list in the `MoreArgs` argument is recycled for each call. Similarly, the second case is recycling both `runif(10)` and `runif(10000)` for each call, giving behavior that I'm confident to call identical. The fourth case only exists to shows what we get if we're silly enough to not use any lists at all.

My above quoted claim is that the first and third cases should be identical. This is clearly not the case. If we try to use one list (rather than two, as our second case did) without `MoreArgs`, R's normal vector recycling rules will have us reuse the value of `runif(10)` for the first, third, and fifth calls, and use `runif(10000)` for the second and fourth, and give us a warning due to this odd behavior.

In conclusion, it still appears that the `MoreArgs` argument can always be replaced by R's vector recycling rules (despite my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66213642/10319707)), but not in the exact way that I said in the question. The truth appears to be that `MoreArgs=list(foo,bar,etc)` is equivalent to using `list(foo)`, `list(bar)`, and `list(etc)` as `...` arguments to `mapply`. Notice that this is not the same as using `list(foo,bar,etc)` as a `...` argument. So, ultimately: **You will not always get identical functionality from omitting the MoreArgs argument.**

As a final minor detail: Omitting the `MoreArgs` argument is harmless, but omitting the `...` argument and using `MoreArgs` instead [gives unexpected output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66789859/10319707), usually an empty list.

Answer (score 3):

If we are passing a named argument, `MoreArgs` can be passed in a `list`.  Sometimes, the argument depends on the order of arguments in the function and it is evaluated in that order. e.g. if we want the specify argument `n`

```
mapply(rnorm, 1:10, 11:20, MoreArgs = list(n = 5),SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

It works even without the `MoreArgs` as well because it does the recycling for each element being passed.  However, passing arguments in `MoreArgs` can help in distinguishing the function arguments from the inputs to the `mapply/Map`.  These are mostly used when we invoke functions without a lambda/anonymous function as it can also be written as

```
mapply(function(x, y) rnorm(n = 5, mean = x, sd = y), 1:10, 11:20, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Note that the below one fails because there are no inputs to `mapply`, but only function argument input

```
mapply(rnorm, MoreArgs = list(n = 5, mean = 1:10, sd = 11:20))
```

---

When we pass the arguments as in the order specified in the OP's post without a name, assuming the `n` is 5, it is not taken as 5, instead it is now the `sd` because the order of `rnorm` is `n`, `mean` and `sd` as showed in the `Usage` of `?rnorm`

> rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)

```
mapply(rnorm, 1:10, 11:20, 5, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

compare this to

```
mapply(rnorm, 5, 1:10, 11:20, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

or

```
mapply(rnorm, 1:10, 11:20, n = 5, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

which can be otherwise written in `MoreArgs` as well as showed in the first syntax

Comment: Isn't that identical to `mapply(rnorm,1:10,11:20,n = 5,SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`?

Comment: @J.Mini It is a convenient way to specify that these are the function arguments and not the inputs to `Map/mapply`.  Because of the recycling it does replicate across all the elements

Comment: This seems very lame. I was aware that anonymous functions can give `mapply` without `MoreArgs` equivalent functionality to `mapply` with `MoreArgs`. After all, such a thing is basically an idiomatic usage of `Map`. However, the idea that the vector recycling rule alone is enough to make `MoreArgs` functionally useless is extremely shocking to me. In fact, it's so shocking that I cannot believe it at all.

Comment: I never should have doubted you. I've posted my own answer and I appear to have went through the longest possible path to discover just how right you were.

Comment: @J.Mini Thanks.  I guess you are more meticulous in learning even the minute details.  Glad to know about that

Comment: I believe that I've discovered that you're subtly wrong. See my latest answer. I've found a case where omitting `MoreArgs` does not give identical functionality.

Answer (score 1):

**Update: I have come to believe that this answer is incorrect. My embolden concern below appears correct, voiding a key part of this answer. For a proper answer, see my other answer.**

Following [Henrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1851712/henrik)'s lead from the comments, we can give an answer. `MoreArgs` is best used for the arguments that you want to recycle, but not in the way that `Mapply` wants to. This is typically the case when said argument is a vector or list. What follows is an extended example.

Consider the `rmultinom` function. It's very badly behaved. It takes 3 arguments: `n` controlling how many samples to take, `size` controlling how big each sample is, and the vector of probabilities `prob`, where each probability in the vector can be seen as the chance that a biased die of `length(prob)` sides rolls the face corresponding to the entry in `prob` in question. Its output is a vector showing the number of times that the biased die landed on each side. For example, this is one possible input and output (read from top to bottom, not left to right):

```
 rmultinom(3,10,c(0.6,0.3,0.1))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    6    6    6
[2,]    2    2    4
[3,]    2    2    0
```

Why do I say that `rmultinom` is badly behaved? Because this is also valid:

```
rmultinom(3,10,c(0.6))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10   10   10
```

You'd think that giving `rmultinom` a vector of probabilities that don't sum to 1 would throw an error, but for technical reasons that I don't claim to understand, it doesn't.

So let's get back to `mapply`. Suppose that I want to test with `n` as 3, 4, and 5 with a sample of `size` 10 for the first test, 11 for the second test, and 12 for the last. I want `prob` to stay fixed at `c(0.6,0.3,0.1)`. If I get that last bit wrong, then we'll get the bad behavior that we had earlier.

Let's start by trying `mapply(rmultinom,3:5,10:12,c(0.6,0.3,0.1))`:

```
mapply(rmultinom,3:5,10:12,c(0.6,0.3,0.1))
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10   10   10

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   11   11   11   11

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   12   12   12   12   12
```

That didn't work. I can tell you that using `list(0.6,0.3,0.1)` as our last argument doesn't work either. It gives exactly the same output, so I won't even shown it. How about forgetting about `c` or `list` and just using `0.6,0.3,0.1` directly?

```
mapply(rmultinom,3:5,10:12,0.6,0.3,0.1)
Error in (function (n, size, prob)  : 
  unused arguments (dots[[4]][[1]], dots[[5]][[1]])
```

No luck there. Because of the way that `rmultinom` works, I can't tell if the vector recycling rule or `mapply` have betrayed us, but I cannot think of any sensible ways to use the recycling rule that we have not already tried. So how about using `MoreArgs` with our original vector?

```
Error in mapply(rmultinom, 3:5, 10:12, MoreArgs = c(0.6, 0.3, 0.1)) : 
  argument 'MoreArgs' of 'mapply' is not a list
```

Alright then, we'll have to use a list...

```
mapply(rmultinom,3:5,10:12,MoreArgs=list(0.6,0.3,0.1))
Error in (function (n, size, prob)  : unused arguments (0.3, 0.1)
```

A list of our vector then!

```
> mapply(rmultinom,3:5,10:12,MoreArgs=list(c(0.6,0.3,0.1)))
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    8    9
[2,]    3    1    0
[3,]    3    1    1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    6    8    4    7
[2,]    4    3    7    3
[3,]    1    0    0    1

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    7    6    9    8    7
[2,]    2    2    3    3    4
[3,]    3    4    0    1    1
```

And now we finally have something that works. Incidentally, `mapply(rmultinom,3:5,10:12,list(c(0.6,0.3,0.1)))` also works, but *I think* that's because `mapply` knows to pass `list(c(0.6,0.3,0.1))` as `MoreArgs=list(c(0.6,0.3,0.1))`. I'd be interested to know if anyone can confirm that. It could be the case that `mapply` is recycling the first entry of `list(c(0.6,0.3,0.1))`, which would be the vector `c(0.6,0.3,0.1)`, **rendering this entire answer false**.

Assuming that the above isn't a case of recycling, then we can confidently say that we couldn't find a vector recycling way to do what we wanted to, which therefore answers the question and shows that we needed `MoreArgs`. But as a bonus, it's worth showing how to do this with anonymous functions:

```
mapply(function(x,y,z) rmultinom(x,y,c(0.6,0.3,0.1)),3:5,10:12)
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    7    4
[2,]    4    2    5
[3,]    1    1    1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    5    7    5    5
[2,]    5    1    5    4
[3,]    1    3    1    2

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   10    8    8    8    8
[2,]    2    2    3    3    3
[3,]    0    2    1    1    1
```

Personally, the anonymous functions way to do it seems a lot more natural, but I suppose that it might get a bit ugly if you have a few too many arguments. `mapply(function(...,z) rmultinom(...,c(0.6,0.3,0.1)),3:5,10:12)` and `mapply(function(...) rmultinom(...,c(0.6,0.3,0.1)),3:5,10:12)` also work, but I have no idea if they're safe or idiomatic.