# Why would Advanced R claim that you cannot supply arguments that do not vary to Map?

Tags: r, purrr, anonymous-function, map-function

The author of Advanced R certainly knows R better than I do. However, [Section 9.4.5](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html#pmap) contains the following claim:

> `Map()` vectorises over all arguments so you cannot supply arguments that do not vary.

But this seems obviously false. For example, I can easily write the following:

```
> Map(function(x,y) x+y,1:3,runif(1))
[[1]]
[1] 1.224857

[[2]]
[1] 2.224857

[[3]]
[1] 3.224857
```

And in fact, the same functionality is found in the author's own `purrr:map` function:

```
purrr::map(1:3,function(x,y) x+y,runif(1))
[[1]]
[1] 1.729889

[[2]]
[1] 2.729889

[[3]]
[1] 3.729889
```

So what might the author have been talking about? I get the feeling that I'm simply misreading, a guess strongly enforced by the fact that [section 9.2.3](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html#passing-arguments) shows off the same sort of functionality in `purrr::map`:

```
plus <- function(x, y) x + y

x <- c(0, 0, 0, 0)
map_dbl(x, plus, runif(1))
#> [1] 0.0625 0.0625 0.0625 0.0625
map_dbl(x, ~ plus(.x, runif(1)))
#> [1] 0.903 0.132 0.629 0.945
```

So what defect in `Map` could the above quote be referring to?

Comment: Since your quibble seems to be with author's choice of words and not the R programming language itself, it would be better to ask the author. The book has a github site if you would like to file an issue there: https://github.com/hadley/adv-r/issues

Comment: @MrFlick I'm working on the assumption that the error is in my reading of the text rather than the text itself.

Comment: Numeric vectors can be recycled to an appraiser length. Try passing a different type of parameter such as a function, list, or matrix as an additional parameter.

Comment: @MrFlick I see no issues or inconsistencies. I think that I'm going to need to see what you have in mind.

Comment: Something like `Map(function(x,fun) fun(1:x),1:3,sum)`. A function like `sum` can't be recycled. And if you wanted to add an item to a list with `Map(function(x,y) c(y,z=x), 1:3, list(a=1, b=2))` and where expecting three, 3-item lists that's not what you get because the value was split up. basically everything needs to be of compatible length. But i'm not sure that's really different than `purrr::map`. So it would be better to ask the author what they meant by that. I think it's getting at the `MoreArgs=` option you can pass to `mapply`.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks. I'll have a good think about that. As for `MoreArgs`, that's almost redundant even in mapply. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66605605/10319707

Comment: @J.Mini I disagree that `MoreArgs` is (almost) redundant. Please refer to the arguments I gave in comments under the question you link to (I won't reiterate them here).

Comment: MoreArgs is for things you don't want to be recycled. There are lots of times you call a function and don't want a particular value to be altered or changed on each iteration. Having the MoreArgs function often makes it easy to skip the step of writing an anonymous function. Especially parameters like `data=` when you are running modeling functions with different parameters.

Comment: @MrFlick It's becoming very clear that I have a great misunderstanding of the `MoreArgs` argument. As explained in the linked answer, I fully believe it to be equivalent to recycling and I also believe that you can always get what appears to be exactly the same functionality by passing the relevant code to `...` rather than `MoreArgs`. You often don't even have to change the code, you just have to delete the string `MoreArgs=`. If I am wrong, please post an answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map` is a wrapper to `mapply`:

```
Map <- function (f, ...) 
{
  f <- match.fun(f)
  mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
}
```

Documentation of `mapply` tells us:

> `mapply` calls `FUN` for the values of ... (re-cycled to the length of the longest, unless any have length zero), followed by the arguments given in MoreArgs. The arguments in the call will be named if ... or MoreArgs are named.

This means that even if you supply an argument that shouldn't vary, it will be recycled as a vector and not kept as it is, as would a standard function argument do.

This makes quite a difference if the non varying argument is itself a vector:

```
f <- function(x,coef) {paste(coef[1],'*', x ,'+',coef[2])}

Map(f,1:3,c(2,3))
[[1]]
[1] "2 * 1 + NA"

[[2]]
[1] "3 * 2 + NA"

[[3]]
[1] "2 * 3 + NA"

Warning message:
In mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) :
  longer argument is not a multiple of length of shorter
```

Conversely, `purrr::map` allows arguments that don't vary, and the difference between these two examples illustrates what the author of the above quote probably means :

```
purrr::map(1:3,f,c(2,3))

[[1]]
[1] "2 * 1 + 3"

[[2]]
[1] "2 * 2 + 3"

[[3]]
[1] "2 * 3 + 3"
```

Comment: See my edit, this illustrates perhaps better the vectorization/recycling problem

Comment: I think that this is the best answer that's we're ever going to get, so I'm going to accept this. However, I can't believe that the book's author is either ignorant of or knowingly omitting the fact that `Map` can already do this. To my knowledge, `Map(f,1:3,list(c(2,3)))` has exactly the same functionality.

Comment: I read your comment about warnings, but after rethinking about it I thought that the warning is a very useful message about the way Map works. Also interesting to see that purrr::map doesn't make a warning because it accepts arguments that don't vary.

Comment: This makes sense : added the warning