# Why does doing variable assignment inside mapply's MoreArgs argument give different results than doing it inside its "..." argument?

Tags: r, mapply

Using the following block of code:

```
x<-1
mapply(sum, list(x<-x+1))
x
mapply(sum, MoreArgs = list(x<-x+1))
x
```

I get the following output:

```
> mapply(sum, list(x<-x+1))
[1] 2

> x
[1] 2

> mapply(sum, MoreArgs = list(x<-x+1))
list()

> x
[1] 3
```

Why do the results from the two uses of `mapply` differ? I was under the [strong impression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66605605/10319707) that I would get the same result.

Comment: If you do an assignment inside a function call, you deserve everything you get

Comment: @HongOoi although I agree that it's bad practice to do the assignment, it's not related to the issue the OP is facing (at least for what I understand). Guess OP wants to know why he had different results depending on the use of `MoreArgs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of times `mapply` iterates depend on the length of the `...` arguments. In the second call you don't provide any argument and so `mapply` iterates 0 times. It doesn't matter what you have passed to `MoreArgs`.

Some examples:

```
mapply(match,integer(0),integer(0))
#list()
mapply(match,integer(0),integer(0), MoreArgs=list(table=1:10))
#list()
mapply(match,integer(0),1:10, MoreArgs=list(nomatch=2))
#Error in mapply(match, integer(0), 1:10, MoreArgs = list(nomatch = 2)) : 
#  zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length
```

Everything is clearly documented in `?mapply`. In the arguments section:

> ...: arguments to vectorize over (vectors or lists of strictly
> positive length, or all of zero length).  See also ‘Details’.

In Details:

> ‘mapply’ calls ‘FUN’ for the values of ‘...’ (re-cycled to the
> length of the longest, unless any have length zero), followed by
> the arguments given in ‘MoreArgs’.

Comment: Can you give some evidence for this? For example, a reference to `mapply`'s code or documentation? Or maybe some example that proves that the behavior is as you describe?

Comment: It's crystal clear from the documentation. I added examples and the relevant sections.